# Finding Network Status of specific process name

Tags: process, netstat, lsof

I am looking for  the cleanest way on linux to find the port status for a port being used by a specified program name via the command line. I have seen that netstat -p lists all pids but haven't seen anything corresponding to specific process names. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically you should see the program name with the paramter -p and the PID.
Be aware that you need root rights to display the program name of processes which arent running under your user.

*-p without root permissions:*

```
$ netstat -lnp
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
...
...
```

*-p with root permissions*

```
$ sudo netstat -lnp
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1553/apache2    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1392/vsftpd     
...
...
```